# Enzyme tests fail due to linting in React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm in the process of upgrading a project to React 16. When I run `yarn test` many tests now fail due to linting/formatting errors e.g.

```
  + expected - actual

             disabled={false}
             name="ticketTime"
             placeholder="Setup instructions.."
             rows={10}
          -  value="Sample text"
          ->
          +  value="Sample text">


...

      -          "label": "one",
      +          "label": "one"
               }
      -      }
      -    >
...

    + expected - actual

           <div>
          -  <h1
          -    key="0"
          -  >
          +  <h1>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix the tests?

Comment: Do you mean that your tests fail because your HTML snapshots have changed?  Have you tried updating them?  Please show the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I haven't updated the snapshots. I guess that's probably the best thing to do where only the formatting of the snapshot is causing a test to fail.

Comment: Yep, that's what they're for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, it sounds like you are using Jest with Enzyme, and probably need to update your snapshots:

```
jest --updateSnapshot
```

This will render your HTML per the current code, to reflect any changes, including linting changes, that may make the HTML different, and update the snapshot files.

When your tests run, they inspect the snapshots, and if they aren't up to date, the tests will fail.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can update your snapshot using:

`yarn test -- -u`